# transform list of data frames to obtain means for df names and yearly means

Tags: r, list, mean

I’m analyzing river streamflow data with R language and I have a list of data frames. Each data frame represents a subbasin (910, 950, 1012 and 1087) and has the exact same structure and number of variables and contains a value of IHA indicators (IHA1, IHA2) per Year (2004:2007)

```
Flowtest <- list("910" = tibble(Year = c(2004:2007), IHA1=c(123, 170, 187, 245), IHA2=c(679, 870, 789, 233)),
                 "950" = tibble(Year = c(2004:2007), IHA1=c(570, 450, 780, 650), IHA2=c(230, 470, 687, 321)),
                 "1012" = tibble(Year = c(2004:2007), IHA1=c(160, 170, 670, 780), IHA2=c(350, 840, 701, 353)),
                 "1087" = tibble(Year = c(2004:2007), IHA1=c(120, 780, 820, 580), IHA2=c(870, 870, 763, 291)))
```

I'd like to obtain 3 data frames as a result, shown in the picture below:

1. calculate means for each IHA (without splitting into subbasins or years)
2. calculate means for each IHA (with splitting into years but without splitting into subbasins)
3. calculate means for each IHA (with splitting into subbasins but without splitting into years)

In reality, my list contains a lot more subbasins and IHA indicators

[image]

For 1. I managed to create this:

```
    test <- Flowtest %>% 
      reduce(bind_rows) %>% 
      summarise_all(mean) %>%
      select(-Year)
```

I would like to create a similar code to the one above to obtain results as shown in 2. and 3. (like in the picture). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Joanna a possible solution would be this:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# bind list to a tibble and make list names to a column
Flowtest_df <- plyr::ldply(Flowtest, data.frame) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(RCH = 1)

# mean
Flowtest_df %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(IHA1_mean = mean(IHA1),
                   IHA2_mean = mean(IHA2))
# year mean
Flowtest_df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Year) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(IHA1_mean = mean(IHA1),
                   IHA2_mean = mean(IHA2))
# RCH mean
Flowtest_df %>%  
  dplyr::group_by(RCH) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(IHA1_mean = mean(IHA1),
                   IHA2_mean = mean(IHA2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
map(list(NULL,'Year','subbasin'), ~bind_rows(Flowtest, .id = "subbasin") %>%
      group_by(.dots = .x)%>%summarise(across(starts_with("IHA"), mean),.groups='drop'))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
   IHA1  IHA2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  453.  582.

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   Year  IHA1  IHA2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2004  243.  532.
2  2005  392.  762.
3  2006  614.  735 
4  2007  564.  300.

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  subbasin  IHA1  IHA2
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 1012      445   561 
2 1087      575   698.
3 910       181.  643.
4 950       612.  427
```